# TimerTask in Android?

Tags: android, timertask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing counter in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027509/implementing-counter-in-android)

I need to implement the TimerTask. the Scenario is I am going to get a response from the server. If the server does not repond more than 10 seconds then i have to navigate to the next activity.

How to implement that? Please Help.