# Implementing counter in Android

Tags: android

I have got an application where I need to show counter from 3 to 1 then quickly switch to another activity. Will TimerTask will be suitable for doing this? Can anybody show me an example of exactly how to do it?

CountDownTimer Worked. Code for showing timer for 3 seconds is.

```
new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 Animation myFadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(countdown.this, R.anim.fadeout);       
                 counter.startAnimation(myFadeOutAnimation);
                 counter.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 counter.setText("done!");
             }
        }.start();
```

Comment: @Sankar Ganesh: cannot get you? Please Elobrate.

Comment: You can have a count Down Timer and set the Timer for 10 sec, if the timer expires then fire new activity

Comment: Yeah i think it will do fine. [Read this to know how to update your UI using a timer task](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would better use a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

If you want for example your counter to count 3 seconds:

```
//new Counter that counts 3000 ms with a tick each 1000 ms
CountDownTimer myCountDown = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //update the UI with the new count
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        //start the activity
   }
};
//start the countDown
myCountDown.start();
```

Comment: there is a small type
this:
CountDownTimer myCountDown = new CountdownTimer(3000, 1000) {
should be this:
CountDownTimer myCountDown = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

Capital D in the new CountDownTimer :)

Comment: Simple but sure! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `CountDownTimer` as shown below.

Step1: create `CountDownTimer` class

```
class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            dialog.dismiss();
           // Use Intent to Navigate from this activity to another
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
}
```

Step2: create an object for that class

```
MyCount counter = new MyCount(2000, 1000); // set your seconds
counter.start();
```