# How to create a thread and call next activity in android ?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

How do I call an activity from my splash screen using threads. just guide me in java code i.e how do i create a thread and call my next activity.

Comment: Please change the title of your question to something more specific (less generic).

Comment: do you have google? If yes then search it you will get as many answers you want for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a splash screen in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the second activity from your SplashActivity :
**Note:** SplashActivity will be the Startup Activity in manafist

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

protected boolean _active = true;
protected int _splashTime = 5000;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);    
    Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                        sleep(100);
                        if(_active) {
                            waited += 100;
                        }
                    }
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                } finally {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.package.AppName.SecondActivity"));
                }
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thankyou BasBous, I couldn't see my splash when i run my project, directly the SecondActivity is visible. How come?

Comment: you wanna show the spalsh screen after the spalsh is disappear you wanna start the second activity

Comment: display the splash first and then connecting to it secondavtivity.

Comment: _active and _splasTime cannot be resovled to a variable

Comment: you can replace all line of code to this 
startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));

Comment: 01-16 15:28:26.025: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1079): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=PhoneDirectory.this, Login.class }

Comment: check that the Login.class added as activity to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".PhoneDirectoryActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />                
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: <activity android:name=".Login"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"> <activity android:name=".PhoneDirectoryActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Login" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity></application> </manifest>

Comment: <intent-filter> <action android:name="com.packagename.classname">

mistake i made