# Android - Splash Screen without making another thread for main UI

Tags: android, multithreading, screen, splash-screen

That's my first question and I'm an Android noob yet (hopefully), so please try to forgive me if I'm asking stupid questions.

I'm working on an Android application and I have to make a splash screen. I made one using this answer: [How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android) . It is working very fine, but... this solution makes another big thread for the rest of application and I am trying to avoid that - I think it slows whole application (another app thread). Am I right?

I tried to invert whole process - I'm invoking MainMenu activity, then making another thread just for splash:

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener { 

private GridView gridView;
private AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
private Intent intent;
private ApplicationPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    prefs = new ApplicationPreferences(this);
    setTheme(prefs.GetApplitacionTheme());
    SQLDatabase.onCreate();

    if (prefs.SplashScreenEnabled()) {
        new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, SplashScreen.class));                   
            }
        }.run();
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new AdapterMainMenu(this));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

Then in my SplashScreen activity:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

private Locale locale;
private Configuration config;
private ApplicationPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finish();               
}
```

After onCreate() Android calls onResume() so I decided to pause thread here and after that finish activity.

When application comes back to the main thread it crashes and I don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Unguis

Comment: Post your LogCat errors.  Why is `startActivity()` in a Runnable?  You should use a Runnable to close the SplashScreen after 2.5 seconds instead of using `sleep()`.

Comment: Your classes naming convention (MainMenu is activity not menu as name indicates) will give you troubles in bigger project...

Comment: Thanks! I will change it to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to call `Thread.sleep()` in `onResume()` because that blocks the UI thread. The solution that you tried first with `Handler.postDelayed()` is definitely the preferred way. Why do you think it creates a "big" thread? `Runnable.run()` is actually called in the main UI thread with that solution.

Comment: Whole app is working in another thread made with Handler.postDelayed() as I think till moment when I end MainMenu activity (app comes back to the SplashScreen where MainMenu was invoked) and then it ends with finish(). I thought it slows whole app. Isn't it?

Comment: if you use the Handler like that, it will always execute the Runnable in the UI Thread, so no other thread is created. Btw: in Android, all the Activity live-cycle methods, like onCreate(), onResume() etc., are always executed in the UI Thread as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer and a handler as below

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity{

Timer splashTimer;
SplashTimerHandler splashTimerHandler;

private boolean applicationPaused=false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.setSplash();


}

private void setSplash() 
{
    this.splashTimerHandler=new SplashTimerHandler();
    this.splashTimer=new Timer();

    this.splashTimer.schedule(this.splashTimerHandler, 0, 1000);

}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    this.applicationPaused=true;
    this.closeSplashTimer();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if(this.applicationPaused)
    {
        this.applicationPaused=false;
        this.closeSplashTimer();
        this.setSplash();
    }
}

public class SplashTimerHandler extends TimerTask{

    int splashTimerCounter=0;
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        splashTimerCounter++;
        if(splashTimerCounter>2)
        {
            runOnUiThread(splashTimeOver);
        }       
    }

    private Runnable splashTimeOver=new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            closeSplashTimer();
            startHomeScreen();
        }
    };      
}

protected void closeSplashTimer() 
{
    if(this.splashTimer!=null)
    {
        this.splashTimer.cancel();
        this.splashTimer=null;
    }

}

private void startHomeScreen() 
{
    this.closeSplashScreen();
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.MainActivity"));

}

private void closeSplashScreen()
{
    this.closeSplashTimer();
    this.finish();

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keycode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        this.closeSplashScreen();
    }
    return true;
}

}
```