# Phonegap splashscreen with embedding cordovawebview

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I have an app with embedded CordovaWebView. Accroding to inctruction, in that case i shouldn't extend my activity from DriodGap.

```
public class CordovaViewTestActivity extends Activity implements CordovaInterface {
    CordovaWebView cwv;
    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialView);
        cwv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

But i need to use splashscreem. Accroding to instruction, i must do like that:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);
```

But my Activity isn't extends from DroidGap. 
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your project's main Java file found in the src folder in Eclipse:

Do the following:

- Add import org.apache.cordova.*;
- Change the class's extend from **Activity** to **DroidGap**

[**more details...**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)

[image]

Comment: It's not works. I need embedded webview, i have some controls in my layout.

Comment: DroidGap is a Cordova activity, which is ONLY a Cordova activity. The op is referring to an activity that EXTENDS the Cordova interface, but is still a regular activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a regular android splash screen. Here is a good stackoverflow discussion about android splash screen: [How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android)

Another way to give the impression of a splash screen is to make your landing page to look like a splash screen and insert a javascript function that will be called after few seconds and will call your current landing page (this way you have "splash screen" for all platforms).

A javascript function can look like the following (assuming your main page is 'index.html':

```
function loadMainPage(){
 setTimeout(function(){this.document.location.href = "index.html"}, 2000);
}
```