# How to start an activity in background and show it afterwards?

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

I've two activities, one is the 
`SplashActivity` and the other is `MainActivity`, an activity containing a webview.

I need to load the webview when showing the splash screen. So I'm looking for a way to load the MainActivity in background in `SplashActivity::onCreate()`;

If intend is directly called, the MainActivity is immediately brought to the front, as well as a stuck in the webview.

I looked up a lot of solutions about splash screen like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android)
. However they don't initialize the MainActivity until the splash time expires.

Comment: You may try using animation by showing the mainactivity late by some milli seconds...

Comment: You could launch the MainActivity first and start the SplashActivity in onCreate() of MainActivity. After the required duration, you could just close the SplashActivity and MainActivity would reappear so that it would appear as if you have started Main from Splash.

Comment: @user1721904 Yeah, I think that idea should work. However could you please provide more details on that? Say, should I use `finish()` to stop the SplashActivity? or should I use intend to start it? Also please write it as an answer. THX

Comment: Posted it as an answer :)

Comment: what you can do is  instead of having 2 layouts you can have one layout and replace the layout after the  time is over

Comment: Yeah, actually I'm trying out this method right now. @HarshDevChandel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android Apps can cache web data. you can use this to your advantage. (and it worked for me).
What I did:

- I created a WebView in the splash screen.
- didn't attach it to the UI,
- requested the webpage I needed in the Main Activity.
- once the WebView in your splash screen is loaded start the other Activity.

the WebView there will use the cache of the WebView you created in the splash screen.

Answer (score 15):

You could launch the `MainActivity` first and start the `SplashActivity` in `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`. After the required duration, you could just close the `SplashActivity` and `MainActivity` would reappear so that it would appear as if you have started Main from Splash.

Let me explain it -

In your `MainActiviy` use an `intent` and start `SplashActivity` by using `startActivity` and not `startActivityForResult` as you would not want to pass back the result from `SplashActivity` to `MainActivity`.

Now that you are in `SplashActivity`, start a thread and wait in the thread for the required duration and then call `finish()` so that `SplashActivity` will close and the previously started `MainActivity` comes to the foreground.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

i hope this should work perfectly...

```
   ProgressDialog pd;   

   pd = ProgressDialog.show(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this,"Loading...", true, false);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this,
                            NEXT_ACTIVITY.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            }).start();

        }
    });
```