# How to start an Activity without showing it

Tags: android, android-activity

In Splash Activity , I want to start my Main Activity first without showing it , so that when Splash Activity is finished , I can just reload Main Activity already started before , this will make loading process of Main Activity faster and more smooth . 
I have found this answer , but this way will show the Main Activity for a while before the Splash Activity showing;

Thanks

Comment: the answer I found is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831229/how-to-start-an-activity-in-background-and-show-it-afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can direct start `MainActivity` and show a custom dialog view similar to your splash screen while `MainActivity` is loading dismiss this dialog once loading is finish.

Comment: This is OK for some case , In my case,  I still need a Splash Activity to finish some task before the Main Activity started, like judging whether the user has log in or not , If the user has log out , I need to start another Activity for the user to log in instead .