# How to set delay between main activity and a new activity

Tags: android

I want a welcome screen to appear and then after a delay of few seconds start a new activity.
Ex. I have mainactivity.java and second activity.java. main activity displays a welcome message and second activity does work. I am using intent to start second activity from main. But the main does not start instead directly second is loaded. Help!!!

Comment: Whats your code for the delay?

Comment: @Steve Benett I have no idea for that. I tried using thread.sleep() but of no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **handler** to do that for example

```
private Handler handler;
private Runnable delayRunnable;

handler = new Handler();
delayRunnable = new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

           Add your intent here for Second Activity
           Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondactivity.class);
             startActivity(i);
    }
};      
handler.postDelayed(delayRunnable, 3000);
```

Comment: Intent i =new Intent(this,secondactivity.class); is showing the following error...
The constructor Intent(new Runnable(){}, Class<ListItems>) is undefined

Comment: use getApplicationContext() instead of this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Splash screen activity replacing your mainactivity, and your secondactivity would be the mainactivity of your app...[here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5486970/2604335) a simple tutorial on how to make a splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postAtTime(splashTimeTask, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 500);

private Runnable splashTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

   }
};
```

Comment: Intent i =new Intent(this,second.class) shows error in run method
The constructor Intent(new Runnable(){}, Class<ListItems>) is undefined

Comment: @arj Intent(FirstClass.this, second.class) should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a splash screen? Try [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/) tutorial, it should get you exactly what you want.