# Android, airpush. How show advertising terms dialog after splash screen?

Tags: android, airpush

How I can show AirPush advertising terms dialog after splash screen?
Now it is showing before splash screen(on application start).

I have code in manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.votn.krymXXXXXX.PushService" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.votn.krymXXXXXX.BootReceiver" android:exported="false" >
          <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

How I can show this advertising terms in Java at choosen moment ? I can' t find any informations about it.

Comment: Airpush and a splash screen!  Good luck with the user reviews!

Answer (score 0):

You can use my splash screen solution [How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android/15832037#15832037)

The airpush dialog will automatically be shown after the splash screen