# Android splash screen while loading MainActivity

Tags: android, multithreading, wait, splash-screen, supportmapfragment

So, I just read this question: [How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android)
But instead of adding a fixed delay (like in the top answer), I wanted to keep the splash screen on while the MainActivity (with a MapFragment) loads.

```
    public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {          
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    synchronized (this) {
                          try {
                            wait(3000);
                            System.out.println("Thread waited for 3 seconds");
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }       
                }
            });
            try {
                t.start();
                t.join();
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

I added the wait(3000) line, because I noticed before that the thread didn't live for long. However, if I make it wait for longer, there's just a black screen that lasts longer. For some reason, **the SplashScreen activity won't show the ImageView**.
What should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: [**Splash screens are evil, don't use them!**](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/)

Comment: Check my optimal and easy solution:
https://medium.com/@vatani.ahmad/android-optimal-splash-screen-without-extra-activity-or-fragment-b60fea45a0cc

Answer (score -3, accepted):

make a splash screen like this:

```
while(counter < 1300) {
    try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        counter+=100;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**
Anotehr way to make a splash would be like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourNextActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
    }
},3000); -> the splash will show for 3000 ms, you can reduce this.
```

Comment: Will try it! I'll make sure to tell you if it does. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't give you the -1, I accepted the answer. (:

Comment: @HugoM.Zuleta Lol it wasnt you :).. someone else did. :).. i just wanted to know the reason so that i could improve if i was wrong..

Comment: reason ? cos it's not correct splash

Comment: Purpose of splash screen is to show the logo till the activity is loaded. Its not meant for a fixed time showing. On slower phones, the splash screen will appear longer and in faster phones it will just flash.

Comment: @nizam.sp: well if u have a better way why not post your answer? Instead of just negating this solution, or whoever it did.

Comment: Check my optimal and easy solution:
https://medium.com/@vatani.ahmad/android-optimal-splash-screen-without-extra-activity-or-fragment-b60fea45a0cc

Answer (score 4):

Easy way to do it..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.tabs.R;

public class Splash extends Activity implements Runnable
{

    Thread mThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        mThread = new Thread(this);

        mThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));

            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

splash.xml if you want to show a image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/splash" >


</LinearLayout>
```

**Note** if you want to do some UI operation in splash .Then you have to create a handler and update UI in it.

Comment: this is not the best way.

Comment: Yes not the best way. there are other ways like TimerTask,Handler,CountDownTimer. Handler is preferable.

Comment: Those aren't the best ways either.

Comment: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/  this guy has shown the best way.

Comment: I have read that article before but it didn't provide any delay and splash doesn't work as it should be.

Comment: that's the actual technique. You should check the splash of Maps or Youtube app. They are using this kind of technique.

Comment: oh i see you work at BoardPeak :D . how can i approach you? email if possible please

Comment: Yes sure, here you go softandweb007@gmail.com .How may I help you?

Comment: I just e-mailed you.

Answer (score 1):

The main thread cannot be blocked for a long time. You should use `Handler` to trigger another event if you want to start another event in 3 seconds. You can use [sendMessageDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageDelayed%28android.os.Message,%20long%29). In addition, `startActivity` should be called in main thread.