# prevent loading blank page when launching android app in the first time

Tags: android, loading

is there any way to prevent the empty view which appear when I load the app in the first time or to change it by any custom view

Comment: What do you mean prevent an empty view? If there is nothing to show there will be empty. If you want to show something then insert it in the editor. Your question is not clear of what you want exactly.

Comment: You can change the background of the activity kinda like a splash screen while it is being loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are searching for is a SplashScreen

Here's an example [Splash Screen Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/)

Or refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5486970/1614108)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have seen the link of splash screen example and what I have done is to add this    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"  to the launched activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dubious progress bar if your app takes some time to launch.
You can also use a simple splash screen.