# Swipe a splash screen to get to a login screen (Android Application)

Tags: android, authentication, swipe, splash-screen

I am developing an android application where currently:
1. splash screen displays
2. splash goes away and login screen appears

What I would like to happen is for the splash screen to stay on the screen until a user swipes the screen left or right which will then bring them to the login screen.

I am relatively new to this and have no idea how to go about implementing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use onTouchListener() to track the swipe movement.

Comment: check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android

and this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be more than one way to achieve this -

1.) Use a View Pager approach - http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

2.) You can detect swipe gesture and than start your login activity and finish Splash Activity. Take a look to start from here - http://goo.gl/Do3z71

Answer (score 0):

Use a ViewPager to achieve what you want:

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html