# Swipe Introduction Splash Screen for First Time Users - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, splash-screen

I want to implement a swipe introduction screen in my Android application that is displayed only when the app is opened for the first time.

[image: This is the swipe tutorial screen shown for the first time when one opens the app SkillPages.]

***This is the swipe tutorial screen shown for the first time when one opens the app SkillPages.***

Can anybody **suggest libraries** that can help me achieve such behaviour.

I will be using Android Studio

Comment: you can achieve using SharedPreferences

Comment: @pblead26 try product tour github android.

Comment: [AppIntro](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro) is one - there are quite a few (**Edit:** If it's the "only run once" behaviour you're after, not the actual tutorial screen, then `SharedPreferences` is indeed the way to go)

Comment: take one boolean and make it true for the first time and save it in sharedPreferences.. check for this every time

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941314/swipe-a-splash-screen-to-get-to-a-login-screen-android-application#answer-21941715) answer helpful to solve similar problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1939

It is also easy to implement this using Fragments, ViewPager and a PageTransformer

Nice tutorial here:

https://medium.com/android-news/creating-an-intro-screen-for-your-app-using-viewpager-pagetransformer-9950517ea04f#.gpa2j0bem

and also check this out

http://blog.grafixartist.com/onboarding-android-viewpager-google-way/

Answer (score 1):

- Store Boolean value using `SharedPreferences` to check if it is for the first time app started or not.
- Check for the value once app is open. for first time value will be false.
- Create `ViewPager` and customize your views with images and show in `Activity`.
- Once this is shown, set true to the shared preference value.
- Each time app opens check for this value, it will return false.
   Check these links [SharedPreference Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and [ViewPager Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)