# Android application doesn't show my custom-made layout

Tags: android

I just finished an android application after watching a tutorial online.I exported it and tested it with BlueStacks and it works fine. The problem is, when i try to run it on my tablet I get an (application has closed) error but the app still starts.I can hear the intro sound but the background for my layout doesen't show. Please help!

THIS IS THE MANIFEST CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.thebasics"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"  
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <!-- .Splash = locatia si numele -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.thebasics.MENU" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".TutorialOne"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.thebasics.TUTORIALONE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>   
    </application>

</manifest>
```

THIS IS THE SPLASH.java CODE:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer muzica;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.splash); 

        MediaPlayer muzica = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.sfx_die);
        muzica.start();

        Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(2000); //2000 = 2 sec
                    Intent splashIntent = new Intent("com.example.thebasics.MAINACTIVITY");

                    startActivity(splashIntent); //porneste activitatea
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
                finally{
                    finish(); //termina activitatea
                }
            }
        };
        logoTimer.start(); //porneste THREADUL
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        muzica.release(); //pune suntetul pe pauza
    }

}
This is the code fore the xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/background" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tutorial1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tutorial2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

AND THIS IS THE MENU CODE:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Menu extends Activity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);


        //Button Sound
        final MediaPlayer sunetButton = MediaPlayer.create(Menu.this,
R.raw.button_click);

        //BUTTON1
        Button tut1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1); 
        tut1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 

            public void onClick(View v){ 
                sunetButton.start(); 
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.thebasics.TUTORIALONE"));

            }

        });


        //BUTTON2
        Button tut2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial2); 
        tut2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){  

            public void onClick(View v){
                sunetButton.start();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.thebasics.TUTORIALONE"));
            }

        });


    }




    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

LOGCAT:

```
build.board: grouper
build.bootloader: 4.23
build.brand: google
build.cpu_abi: armeabi-v7a
build.cpu_abi2: armeabi
build.device: grouper
build.display: KOT49H
build.fingerprint: google/nakasi/grouper:4.4.2/KOT49H/937116:user/release-keys
build.hardware: grouper
build.host: kpfi7.cbf.corp.google.com
build.id: KOT49H
build.manufacturer: asus
build.model: Nexus 7
build.product: nakasi
build.radio: unknown
build.serial: 015d46d970580011
build.tags: release-keys
build.time: 1386200268000
build.type: user
build.user: android-build
version.codename: REL
version.incremental: 937116
version.release: 4.4.2
version.sdk_int: 19

--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
03-05 01:46:20.770 I/dalvikvm(27811): Enabling JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 10...
03-05 01:46:21.160 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 123K, 2% free 7973K/8132K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 31ms
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/ProcessManager(27811): waitpid on failed exec failed: No child processes
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): Cannot obtain root
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su] Working Directory: null Environment: null
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:246)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:189)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at com.nolanlawson.logcat.b.m.a(Unknown Source)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at com.nolanlawson.logcat.b.w.a(Unknown Source)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at com.nolanlawson.logcat.b.p.b(Unknown Source)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at com.nolanlawson.logcat.d.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
03-05 01:46:21.230 W/m       (27811): ... 12 more
03-05 01:46:21.860 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 131K, 2% free 8353K/8520K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 24ms
03-05 01:46:21.860 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
03-05 01:46:21.860 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
03-05 01:46:21.890 I/Choreographer(27811): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 01:46:22.410 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 62K, 2% free 8699K/8796K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 29ms
03-05 01:46:35.990 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 137K, 3% free 9018K/9204K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 20ms
03-05 01:46:35.990 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
03-05 01:46:36.020 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 446K, 7% free 8898K/9540K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
03-05 01:46:36.030 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 8980K/9540K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-05 01:46:36.030 I/dalvikvm-heap(27811): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.881MB for 83216-byte allocation
03-05 01:46:36.050 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 9061K/9624K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-05 01:46:36.060 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 9062K/9624K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-05 01:46:36.060 I/dalvikvm-heap(27811): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.961MB for 83216-byte allocation
03-05 01:46:36.080 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 9143K/9708K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-05 01:46:36.090 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 9145K/9708K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
03-05 01:46:36.100 I/dalvikvm-heap(27811): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.042MB for 83216-byte allocation
03-05 01:46:36.110 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 9226K/9792K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
03-05 01:46:36.130 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 9228K/9792K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
03-05 01:46:36.130 I/dalvikvm-heap(27811): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.124MB for 83216-byte allocation
03-05 01:46:36.150 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 9309K/9876K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
03-05 01:46:36.170 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 9310K/9876K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
03-05 01:46:36.170 I/dalvikvm-heap(27811): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.204MB for 83216-byte allocation
03-05 01:46:36.190 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 9391K/9960K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
03-05 01:46:36.200 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 9392K/9960K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-05 01:46:36.200 I/dalvikvm-heap(27811): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.284MB for 83216-byte allocation
03-05 01:46:36.220 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 9473K/10044K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-05 01:46:36.240 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 9476K/10044K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
03-05 01:46:36.240 I/dalvikvm-heap(27811): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.366MB for 83216-byte allocation
03-05 01:46:36.250 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 9557K/10128K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
03-05 01:46:36.270 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 9638K/10212K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
03-05 01:46:36.290 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 9719K/10296K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-05 01:46:36.310 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 9803K/10380K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-05 01:46:36.320 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 9967K/10548K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-05 01:46:36.340 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 10130K/10716K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-05 01:46:36.360 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 10374K/10968K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-05 01:46:37.660 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 118K, 3% free 10997K/11304K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
03-05 01:46:37.680 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 39K, 4% free 11760K/12128K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
03-05 01:46:56.920 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 609K, 6% free 12313K/13084K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
03-05 01:46:56.950 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 363K, 8% free 12729K/13720K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
03-05 01:46:56.980 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 488K, 7% free 13380K/14356K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
03-05 01:46:57.080 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 574K, 8% free 14084K/15204K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
03-05 01:46:57.480 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1199K, 11% free 14352K/16084K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
03-05 01:46:58.720 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 679K, 8% free 15203K/16448K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
03-05 01:47:00.580 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 679K, 10% free 16055K/17752K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
03-05 01:47:00.800 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1276K, 13% free 16464K/18752K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
03-05 01:47:12.220 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1972K, 17% free 16287K/19420K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
03-05 01:47:12.870 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1505K, 15% free 16525K/19420K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
03-05 01:47:20.890 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4341K, 28% free 14128K/19420K, paused 20ms, total 21ms
03-05 01:47:20.930 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 27K, 17% free 16229K/19420K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 24ms
03-05 01:47:20.930 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
03-05 01:47:23.820 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3543K, 21% free 15505K/19420K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 25ms
03-05 01:47:23.820 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
03-05 01:47:25.540 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5621K, 37% free 12390K/19420K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 29ms
03-05 01:47:49.080 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3709K, 43% free 10216K/17620K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 35ms
03-05 01:47:49.080 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 28ms
03-05 01:47:49.120 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 51K, 38% free 10981K/17620K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 32ms
03-05 01:47:49.120 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 25ms
03-05 01:47:49.170 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 32% free 12040K/17620K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 26ms
03-05 01:47:49.170 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
03-05 01:48:21.010 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3552K, 44% free 9877K/17460K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 24ms
03-05 01:48:21.010 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
03-05 01:48:21.050 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 18K, 40% free 10593K/17460K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 24ms
03-05 01:48:21.050 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms
03-05 01:48:21.090 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 34% free 11570K/17460K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 26ms
03-05 01:48:21.090 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
03-05 01:48:24.540 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 60K, 28% free 12728K/17460K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 38ms
03-05 01:48:58.820 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3631K, 39% free 10711K/17380K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 29ms
03-05 01:48:58.820 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
03-05 01:48:58.860 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 36K, 33% free 11652K/17380K, paused 6ms+4ms, total 29ms
03-05 01:48:58.860 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 23ms
03-05 01:48:58.900 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 26% free 12954K/17380K, paused 5ms+5ms, total 28ms
03-05 01:48:58.900 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 23ms
03-05 01:49:07.380 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 159K, 12% free 14554K/16404K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 28ms
03-05 01:49:07.380 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 22ms
03-05 01:50:25.970 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27811): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-05 01:50:33.470 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4015K, 25% free 12699K/16824K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
03-05 01:50:33.520 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 149K, 16% free 14179K/16824K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 26ms
03-05 01:50:33.520 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
03-05 01:50:40.530 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27811): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-05 01:50:50.550 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3602K, 26% free 12582K/16808K, paused 21ms, total 22ms
03-05 01:50:50.600 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 31K, 16% free 14179K/16808K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 24ms
03-05 01:50:50.600 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
03-05 01:51:16.350 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27811): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-05 01:51:25.320 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3628K, 26% free 12509K/16740K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
03-05 01:51:25.360 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 38K, 17% free 14018K/16740K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 25ms
03-05 01:51:25.360 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 22ms
03-05 01:51:30.360 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27811): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-05 01:51:39.970 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3606K, 26% free 12503K/16728K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 28ms
03-05 01:51:39.970 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
03-05 01:51:40.010 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 32K, 17% free 14019K/16728K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 25ms
03-05 01:51:40.010 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
03-05 01:51:51.000 I/Choreographer(27811): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 01:51:51.010 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3609K, 25% free 12430K/16404K, paused 6ms+4ms, total 36ms
03-05 01:51:51.460 D/dalvikvm(27811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1227K, 23% free 12783K/16404K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 38ms
03-05 01:51:51.460 D/dalvikvm(27811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
```

TUTORIALONE CODE:

```
package com.example.thebasics;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TutorialOne extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

    TextView textOut;
    EditText textIn;
    RadioGroup gravityG, styleG;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorialone);
        textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvChange);
        textIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        gravityG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgGravity);
        styleG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgStyle);


        //RADIO GROUPS
        gravityG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        styleG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


        //BUTTON
        Button genereaza = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGenerate);
        genereaza.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            textOut.setText(textIn.getText());              
            }
        });
    }


    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }


    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        switch (checkedId){
        case R.id.rbLeft:
            textOut.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            break;  
        case R.id.rbCenter:
            textOut.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            break;
        case R.id.rbRight:
            textOut.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            break;
        case R.id.rbNormal:
            textOut.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL), Typeface.NORMAL);
            break;
        case R.id.rbItalic:
            textOut.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC), Typeface.ITALIC);
            break;
        case R.id.rbBold:
            textOut.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD), Typeface.BOLD);
            break;
        }   
    }
```

}

Comment: can you provide more info

Comment: @CChi - normally when I install an app, a folder is created in sdcard/android/data/com.example.name ,but when I install my app, no folder is created there, i guess it has something to do with that! What kind of other info would you like me to give so you can help me better ?

Comment: Post LogCat from your project. It'll help to understand your "app has closed" error.

Comment: Could you post logcat?

Comment: I posted the logCat, hope it`s ok, I never used it before!

Comment: @Sunil I hope the log is good. I only started learning Android 2 weeks ago, so I`m kind of new to this !

Comment: Can you post the code you have in "com.example.thebasics.TUTORIALONE"? There is something which is requesting permissions but your tablet is denying it.

Comment: @Sunil - I posted the code from tutorialone. I have a Nexus7, if that helps!

Comment: Someone has posted an answer - can you let me know if that solves it. I have other questions in your code though as TutorialOne is not the same as TUTORIALONE (case sensitivity). If the answer posted does not work for you, try changing startActivity() to startActivity(this, TutorialOne.class) and make sure you import the class at the top (or have them in the same package).

Comment: @Sunil  - I tried that and it doesen't work. The code work's perfectly. The only problem I have is that the background image(from the drawable folder) doesen't appear! On the emulator it appears, but on the tablet...zero, nada, null !

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code. It works by it.

Simply change your class name(Menu) to MainActivity. Quick fix rename compilation unit to MainActivity.

By here, Change Menu to MainActivity.

(final MediaPlayer sunetButton = MediaPlayer.create(Menu.this,R.raw.button_click);)

2 places needed to be fix !
And Check onClick() after it ! coz i got error when click !

Good Luck !

Comment: I changed the names but still doesn't work! The background from my drawable folder (that i custom-made) doesn't load. Everything else on the other hand works perfectly fine! The program does what it suposed to do, but without a background image.Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. The error stopped when i changed everything from splash.java with this [How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android)

The background images started working after I changed them with other ones!