# What is this loading-like menu?

Tags: android

I've been programming with Android and have a Facebook login - Whenever my app starts up or is logging into Facebook it throws up this screen:

[image: Image of loading-like screen]

I've been unable to correctly name this screen nor have I been able to find it on Google.

I'm wishing to make changes to its design - Primarily change the action-bar as my apps actionbar doesn't have the logo nor the app name.

Does anyone know what this screen is called, and where I can find documentation on it?

I don't know if its relevant, but the spinning loading circle is only present when this screen shows via the Facebook login - The screen also shows if you start the app up after force stopping it but without the circle.

Comment: @Downvoter - Care to explain?

Comment: Don't know what that was about, but i got it back to neutral for you. So did you have any luck with what I suggested?

Comment: I've corrected the answer Gareth, the last one was written in C# (xamarin) and XML and I had forgot to specify that. The updated one is in Java and XML

Answer (score 0):

This "loading screen" is called a splash screen.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android) is a good stackoverflow on how to change your splash screen (important/key/needed steps listed below). It will also remove the action bar in the splash screen as well.

Key parts of link:

> **Add Splash Screen Image**
>
> First you need a splash screen image. Because Android devices come in
> various resolutions, you may want to ship several splash screens as
> described in Google's Best Practices for Supporting Multiple Screens.
> For simplicity, we'll just ship one here that is 480x800. It should
> support most phone sizes pretty well, and Android will scale it as
> best it can.
>
> Add the the image/gif you want  into your Resources\Drawable
>
> You need to define the spash screen in your layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

          <ImageView id="@+id/splashscreen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:src="@drawable/splash"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"/>

          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"  <!-- Not needed->-->
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello World, splash"/> <!--Not Needed -->

  </LinearLayout>
```

> And your activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    /** Duration of wait **/
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
                Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                Splash.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer - I had never thought of it as a splash screen but it makes sense. I'll give it a go and mark this as the answer if it works.