# Add an image to an android splash screen in intellij android studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, png, splash-screen

Okay so what I'm wanting to do is add an image to my splash screen, so it displays the image before the app starts. I think(?) I found the right code to actually do the splash screen but I can't get the image in it. From what I've read it needs to be in a png file, which it is but how do I move it from a file on my computer to the code, and then where do I go from there?

Comment: `I think(?) I found the right code to actually do the splash screen` Mind explaining what you've tried. This will give us a starting place to help explain how to continue from where you are.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android this is the code that i've tried

Comment: Then all you need to do is put your image in the `app/main/src/res/drawable` folder and name it `spalsh.png`. I strongly encourage you to read about the directory structure of an Android Studio project.

Comment: @AhmadVatani Please post an answer that summarizes your solution.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have **exactly** the code given in [How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android) then you simply need to save your picture as `splash.png` in the `app/main/src/res/drawable` folder. Be sure to clean and rebuild your project before running it. Note that you can give the PNG any name you want. Just change `splash` in `android:src="@drawable/splash"` to match the name you use. Also, I strongly encourage you to learn about the directory structure in an Android Studio project.

Answer (score 0):

My post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567385/what-is-this-loading-like-menu/26568565#26568565) answers this question.

To "move" the image from a file to your code, you need to place it into your drawable folder, then refrence it somewhere by using

```
@drawable/image
```

To better understand how to change the splash screen image please read below.

> **Add Splash Screen Image**
>
> First you need a splash screen image. Because Android devices come in
>   various resolutions, you may want to ship several splash screens as
>   described in Google's Best Practices for Supporting Multiple Screens.
>   For simplicity, we'll just ship one here that is 480x800. It should
>   support most phone sizes pretty well, and Android will scale it as
>   best it can.
>
> Add the the image/gif you want  into your Resources\Drawable
>
> You need to define the splash screen in your layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

          <ImageView id="@+id/splashscreen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:src="@drawable/splash"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"/>

          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"  <!-- Not needed->-->
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello World, splash"/> <!--Not Needed -->

  </LinearLayout>
```

> And your activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    /** Duration of wait **/
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
                Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                Splash.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that C#? I think a Java answer will be more helpful since the OP tagged the question with `android-studio`.

Comment: Yes, the last part is in C#, I nearly forgot to mention that this requires [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/download) to use. I'll correct the code to work in android studio

Comment: If you want to save the time, there is already a Java answer here on SO. The OP linked to it in the comments to the question and I have voted to close as a duplicate.