# Android Title Bar and Icon

Tags: android, user-interface, styles

When my app starts up i see the title bar and the application name with a white activity.
Even though my mainactivity is a splash screen, it does not start at first, but after 2 seconds of this Title bar and white activity. How do i disable this.

thanks for the help!

Splash.java

```
`public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle parameter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        super.onCreate(parameter);
        Thread timer= new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    //Display for 3 seconds
                    sleep(3000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {   
                    //Goes to Activity  StartingPoint.java(STARTINGPOINT)
                    Intent openstartingpoint=new Intent("com.vault.beta.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(openstartingpoint);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
`
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vault.beta"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Vault - Login" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.vault.beta.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".Screen"
            android:label="Calender" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.vault.beta.SCREEN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MenuList"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.vault.beta.MENULIST" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Password"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.vault.beta.PASSWORD" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".EditNote"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.vault.beta.EDITNOTE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Probably you are declaring another activity in your manifest. Could you copy/paste the manifest file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a splash screen in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android#15832037)

Comment: @ben75 the question is not about creating the splash screen. pls read the question before voting down. My problem is, the splash screen activity being the Launcher activity is preceded by a blank body with the title bar, app icon and app name.

Comment: First activity that runs is Splash. What you mention is that splash activity runs but afterwards another layout appears, is that correct?

Comment: No, a blank activity with Title bar, icon and app name runs BEFORE splash activity. for about 3 seconds @TrebiaProject.

Comment: How many times are you calling setContentView() in yout Splash activity?

Comment: only once, in a loop after the time is elapsed.

Comment: Um... can you call it at the very beginning?

Comment: tried that , but same result. there is one more app where in it does not have a splash screen. But main activity  is delayed.

Comment: @PavanKumar I didn't downvote (but vote to close). The duplicate that I suggest is explaining how to avoid what you call "*blank body with the title bar, app icon and app name*" and it is what you are asking no ?

Comment: Possibly you're doing some UI thread blocking in your splash activity `onCreate()` so that only the theme background gets displayed. Post the code there.

Comment: @laalto posted the splashscreen code.

Comment: hum... this is not code for a *splashscreen*, this is code for an Activity with an ImageView

Comment: is it? ok ben! ill refer to the link u pasted here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the theme of the main activity

android:theme="Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"

Comment: Done, still the same result. a blank activity still appears for 3 ~4 seconds

Comment: @PavanKumar it is NOT a blank activity : it is the default background of the current theme.