# Android studio Activity

Tags: android

How do you start an activity for a few seconds and then start another activity.
I tried this code,when I try the app, it directly starts my MainActivity:

```
 Thread timer=new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {

                sleep(5000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {

            }
            Intent intent = new Intent("app.my.com.newapp.MAINACTIVITY");
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    };
timer.start();
```

And here its my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/danger"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Introduction"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_introduction">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="app.my.com.newapp.MAINACTIVITY"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>


   </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Please help me out!!

Comment: you mean you want to create splash screen ?

Comment: yes i would like to make a splash screen

Comment: Refer the given answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a splash screen in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code to create a splash screen.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_layout);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginScreenActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your manifest to see your first activity, your launcher activity should be Introduction and the other `activity` tag will define your MainActivity.
It seems you want to create a splashscreen, here is a [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/)

which might help you.

Answer (score 0):

rename your Activity's name to the other and put the `timer` thread code in `onStart()` of `Introduction` Activity. then all will do as you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

We could connect a Handler to our activity and post a Runnable via the Handler.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private Runnable timedLaunch = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // call the intent from here
        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
        // launch after 5 seconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(timedLaunch , 5000);
    }


    // be sure to remove the callback in case the user leaves the activity before the the given number of seconds have passed

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTask);
    }
}
```

Or we could use a TimerTask(java.util.TimerTask) like this:

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // launching code goes here
  }

 }
```

Then create the timer to be scheduled for a given delay:

```
MyTimerTask myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();

// runs after 5 seconds
timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 5000);
```