# How do I add logo on my start screen in android app?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, oncreate, main-activity

I m making book finder app for the website, i want the logo to be on screen when the user first time launches the app

Here is my code for Main Activity onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_view) ;

}
```

But it does not work

I want it to look like this:

[image: logo]

Comment: Do you want to create Splash Screen ?

Comment: every time it is showing?

Comment: Create splash screen with handler and launcher activity

Answer (score 4):

You should create a Splash Screen,

1 : Create one new Activity with your home screen design (as you mentioned above)

2: Set this new Activity (Splash Screen) as your home Activity

3: Finally, in your new Activity or Splash Activity close or finish your Splash Activity (after 4-5 seconds using Timer) and start or open next Activity which you want..

Thats it..

Same you can get here [How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen)

Answer (score 1):

1.Create seperate .java file for splashscreen Activity.

2.Create splashScreen .xml file seperately.

3.Open your your AndroidManifest.xml file and make your splash screen activity as Launcher activity.

```
 <activity
        android:name="packagepath.SplashScreen"



        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Try those steps .And if you want more help when doing this inform me. IF you got this inform me also