# Android Starting Page With Logo

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to make a page with logo before the app starts like snapchat does (with a loading mark) What is that pages called an Activity page?

[Sample image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pimbv0ubru7rnt/2015-05-11-21-07-59.png?dl=0)

Comment: It's called a Splash Screen.

Comment: splash screen is what i am waitin for thank. If you add as an answer i'll mark it true answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of Activity is called a Splash Screen.

You can check this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen) to find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple activity that starts before the main one, I suggest you do more basic research on android

Answer (score 0):

Create two activities in android put your logo in first one usually called launcher activity and called second one and put the waiting time.
//First one in StartActivity and second one is login

```
int waitTime = 4 * 1000;    //4 seconds

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }, waitTime);   
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```