# How to hold SplashActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have following activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                     Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                     SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                     SplashActivity.this.finish();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // Handle error
                }
            });
    CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(mCtx).addToRequestQueue(req);
  }
}
```

It show `SplashActivity` while request is sending, and when the response is received open other activity. It is ok, except that i need show `SplashActivity` at least 4 seconds. So how i can do next:

If since the beginning of the show activity passed 4 second and got  response show `MainActivity` else wait?

Comment: used `Handler` for that

Comment: if you mean something like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5486970/3411682 I can not figure out how to check I received an response or not, and if not then wait until the request will be recived?

Comment: used `Chronometer` then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response use timer

```
    private final int DELAY  = 4000;

    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                  @Override
                   public void run() {

                   Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                 SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                 SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }

            timer.cancel();

           }
    }, DELAY);
```

Comment: but if the time of the request took a long time, let it be 5 seconds then waiting time will be 5 seconds + DELAY

Comment: For that use System.currentTimeMillis() before request call and in success once again System.currentTimeMillis() to find the difference if it less than 5 second then Delay will be 5000 - remaining time if it is more then no need to call timer directly start MainActivity