# How to easily switch from one activity to another activity in designing an Android application using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Tell me an easy way to do it while opening the application with the name and then the regular activity

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, can you be more specific?

Comment: What did you try already ?

Comment: I haven't tried please tell me in a stepwise manner

Comment: I have buttons in my first activity, help me in such a way that when I click on that button I proceed to next activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing this you can start one activity from another:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

**EDIT:**

if you need a splash screen, here is a solution for it:

[How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen)

```
/** Duration of wait **/
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
     * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
            Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            Splash.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
```

Comment: did you try it? is that what you were looking for????

Comment: Yeah I tried it and I was successful

Comment: Can u now please help to add an activity at the starting of my application that should go on for few seconds and should switch on to some other activity without the user clicking on any button

Comment: do you mean some splash screen??

Comment: Exactly  I have already designed  two activities for my app and now I want to design a splash screen using eclipse

Comment: Now do help me to create a login page after splash screen

Comment: Totally in my application I m going to have 4 activities  and 3 of them are designed and are being connected now I think I need to add 2nd activity by creating  a login page