# Blank screen on debug of Xamarin app

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am not sure if it is just me, or everyone else out there, but every time i debug my Xamarin app on my mobile device i get a blank screen with an actionbar. The screen is displayed for about 2 seconds before it actually loads my specified screen.

Here is my PCL App.cs file:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new LogInPage();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

The blank screen:

[image]

and then finally, after a few seconds:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is the default theme of the Activity being shown while Xamarin Forms is being initialized. You will tend to see this during a cold start. One way to work around it is to add a [Splash Screen](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19362/xamarin-forms-splashscreen-in-android) to show during initialization ([Xamarin Android Splash Screen doc](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/)).

Comment: Or you could append a layout to show instead of the splash screen.

Comment: @ZverevEugene, where would one do that?

Comment: @ZverevEugene I would not suggest using a layout over a theme background based splash screen, due to the fact that it takes longer to inflate a layout. Here is a nice post [Splash Screens the Right Way by Chris Stewart](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) explaing the benefits.

Comment: @PlaceHold3r This is a questionable statement. So-so modern devices  (launched up to 5 years ago) have no problem using layouts as splash-screens at all. Layout really saves app package size (several MBs) compared to all the images one would have to provide for all the possible HDPIs.

Comment: @DustyRoberts There is a layout designer built both into Xamarin for Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio.

Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen

Comment: @ZverevEugene, using a splash screen via the theme will always be quicker (executes earlier in the app life cycle) even it only fractions of a second. Additionally, it never runs the risk of flashing the user with a default themed activity if for whatever reason their device is running slow to inflate the layout. In terms of increasing the size of the package, if done right using a theme background will require no additional image resources than if done via a layout with a single image logo i.e. center image logo and apply a colour background to fill the screen (1 image for each dpi).