# Show message if internet is off as the splash screen loads

Tags: android

I have written this code in `SplashScreenActivity` in `onCreate()`:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
    boolean checkConnection=new MainActivity().checkConnection(this);
    if (checkConnection) {
      t.schedule(new SplashScreenActivity(), 3000);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                "connection not found...plz check connection", 3000).show();
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> The method schedule(TimerTask, Date) in the type Timer is not
>   applicable for the arguments (SplashScreenActivity, int)

Comment: activities are not meant to be created like that. you should override onCreate. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5486970/26224

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never instantiate an `Activity` with the `new` keyword.

You could for example make `checkConnection()` a method of `SplashScreenActivity`.

The cause of the error is the `schedule()` method expects a `TimerTask` as its first parameter, but you're passing an `Activity` to it.

Something like this should work:

```
if (checkConnection) {
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, 3000);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this,
            "connection not found...plz check connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```