# Can A WindowBackground Be Positioned Below The Status Bar & Above The Navigation Bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen, android-theme

Based on [this tutorial](http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832037/1406986), which also references [this other tutorial](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd), using a theme's `android:windowBackground` along with a `<layer-list/>` appears to be the most approved method of creating an Android Splash Screen

Using this technique centering a logo on screen is easy; however, I want to position graphics along the top or bottom of the screen. I've run into problems because, as seen in the screenshot below, the `windowBackground` appears to be drawn behind both the Status Bar at the top of the screen and the Navigation Bar at the bottom thus making the graphics appear cut-off

---

[image]

---

**Question:** *Is it possible to instruct the `windowBackground` to position itself below the Status Bar and above the Navigation Bar? If not, using the `windowBackground` Splash Screen technique is it possible to create a splash screen that isn't covered by the Status Bar or Navigation Bar?*

To reproduce the problem, create a new Android Studio project which will get you the `ic_launcher` drawable and follow one of the tutorials linked above but use the following `layer-list` drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="#000000"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 22):

You may set `windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` to `false` in your theme for lollipop and higher versions.

Example:
res/values-v21/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Theme.Splash">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```