# Why isn't my splash screen showing up upon running emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, splash-screen, android-studio-2.2

I want to make a splash screen come to fruition for 3 seconds whenever the user taps the app icon on his/her phone.  Below is my code.  I don't see what the problem is.  I have no errors (no red squiggly lines) on any of these files.

Here's my `splash.java` file:

```
package org.example.name.tamsky;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Thread myThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

Here's my `activity_splash.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="org.example.name.tamsky.splash">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="org.example.name.tamsky">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error I'm getting when I try to run the emulator is:

```
Error running MainActivity: 
The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter
```

Comment: I don't think you can startActivity from Thread (Worker thread). It should be from UI thread.  Use Handler instead for delaying.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5486970/2956135

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Manifest.xml try to change this line:

`<activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>`

to:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using handler

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH=500;
    Tracker mTracker;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        },SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
}
```