# Can't remove custom splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I made a splash screen for my android app - therefore I followed the 3 steps described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832037/7589266

As I didn't like the result, I directly reversed the 3 steps. But the splash screen still showed up. Furthermore, I deleted the app from my smartphone, cleaned the project and rebuilt it. If I run the code now on the emulator, there doesn't show up a splash screen, but it still does on my physical device.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please post your code? Thanks

Comment: I can post the code, which files do you want see? But I have to say I don't know whether it would help, because I just followed the 3 steps described in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/15832037/7589266 - right after that I removed everything what I've been done in these steps but the splash screen still remains. So you won't find any reference to the splash screen in my MainActivity or my layout files.