# How to collapse floating action button automatically in android

Tags: android, floating-action-button

When I am expanding floating action button it keep remain expanded until I click on that again to collapse.

My question is there any way to automatically collapse floating action button after some times from expanding state.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Handler with a delay:

```
public class HideFabActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private final int DELAY = 5000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final FloatingActionButton fab =(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fab.hide();
            }
        }, DELAY);
}
```

[Check out this SO post re using Handler to make a Splash page.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen)