# Android - View As Splash Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, splash-screen

I tried to make a splash screen for my app as described here:
[How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen/15832037#15832037)
This works pretty fine if I use a single `image/drawable` resource.

But if I create a layout (even with only one image!) as splash screen it won't work; it'll only take longer the app to start and when it opens, it shows the normal layout directly.

Comment: Provide your code in styles and splash.xml and java

Comment: and your manifest.xml as well

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't pasted any code, I don't know if you want help with your code or a suggestion regarding Splash Screens. However, [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) is the best guide I've seen of how to use Splash screens.

Basically, you create a `drawable`with the desired splash screen image.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/white"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/peem_logo"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Next, create a `style` for your splash activity:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Make your Activity as `Launcher` and then in it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

That's all you need.

Comment: thanx, it works ;) - but how to scale the images to dp-values?

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know that. :(

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please accept it, so it can help others.

Answer (score -1):

Try this libraries **[AwesomeSplash](https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AwesomeSplash)**, it provides you many different animation.

compile 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'