# Creating a splash screen in Android studio Version 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, react-native, splash-screen

Can not seem to find a guide that helps me create a splash screen for my android project done in android studio.

(I am working on a mac)

I can not find where to add a new activity so I can create the splash screen.

Edit: Can not find from the areas I was told to try: photos below
SecondEDIT: This is a React-Native Project

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OF6p.png)

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avysP.png)

Comment: I guess you're clicking on the resource folders. You should be clicking on the app>src>com.yourpackagename.

Comment: exactly @SripadRaj is right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen)

Comment: You can add new activity with src-main->Java -> Package

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

[image]

Then set the new activity as the launcher activity and using a handler, set the next activity after a delay:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent nextIntent = new Intent(mContext, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(nextIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 1000); //1000ms = 1second
```

Comment: @DominicGozza so while you are in android studio, just click on file in the top left of the screen then click new -> Activity -> Empty Activity, then you will have added a new activity to your project, just like your question asks

Comment: @DominicGozza in your project structure pane down the left hand side of android studio, click on the "app" file, then follow the instructions above

Comment: Check picture 1 above! please!

Comment: @DominicGozza check the comment above

Comment: Sorry. I meant picture 1 not 2.

Comment: @DominicGozza you still haven't followed my instructions, select the "app" folder, then go to file -> new -> Activity -> Empty Activity

Comment: Sorry but even then the new>Activity>Empty Activity still does not appear.

Comment: @DominicGozza restart android studio

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class in some of your package, create a layout file for that and add it to mainfest under application tag with  tag and you can get the Splash type functionality in following way:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final long SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY = 2000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            User user = GeneralUtils.getRegisteredUser(SplashActivity.this);
            if (user == null || user.getUserId() == null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, WalkThroughActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            SplashActivity.this.finish();

        }
    };

    countDownTimer.start();
}
```

}