# unable to add splash screen in application

Tags: android

I am new to android studio. I want to learn how to convert webview to app. I have written the code for the same :

`activity_main.xml` is as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.aarvansh.shoponline.shoponline.MainActivity">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

`AndroidMenifest.xml` is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aarvansh.shoponline.shoponline">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

`Main Activity.java` is :

```
package com.aarvansh.shoponline.shoponline;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://aarvanshinfotech.co.in/shop");

    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }

    @Override
    // This method is used to detect back button
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to run this apk, no splash screen is being load at the start. I want to load splash screen in which I want to rotate a jpg file when the app is loading

Comment: Where is a splash screen ?

Comment: your code not related about splash screen!

Comment: you need to add one more activty i.e splash and make this activity as a launcher activity and then redirect to MainActivity

Comment: It's not really clear what you've tried or why you're expecting a slash screen to exist

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen

Answer (score 2):

You need to create another activity for splash screen

Check the below code foe splash screen

create a new empty activity than just use below code

customize your splash screen as per your requirement

> **SAMPLE CODE**

**LAYOUT file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ACTVITY Code**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();    

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {   

                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);             
                    finish();                      

            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your android project to load splash screen. U can change the logo image in splashscreeen.xml as per ur need .

SplashScreenActivity.java

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Window;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

    // Set Duration of the Splash Screen
    long Delay = 8000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Remove the Title Bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Get the view from splash_screen.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        // Create a Timer
        Timer RunSplash = new Timer();

        // Task to do when the timer ends
        TimerTask ShowSplash = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Close SplashScreenActivity.class
                finish();

                // Start MainActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        };

        // Start the timer
        RunSplash.schedule(ShowSplash, Delay);
    }
}
```

splash_screen.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/LogoImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LogoImage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    </ProgressBar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml
                 In your Manifest file Change the application part as below...

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```