# How to change Activity Priority in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Iam trying to add Splash screen to my existing Android Project, which is not `MainActivity.Java`, but by default  Android Studio is executing `MainActivity.Java` first, So I want to change the Activity Priority so that my `SplashActivity.Java` will execute first and later Activity's will follow after the Splash Screen.

Comment: you should pass through some basic Android training before you continue to eliminate 100 more such questions.

Answer (score 3):

Make splash activity your launcher activity instead of Main Activity in Android Manifest.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ui.splash.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

modify your AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.circlefil.reactivetrip">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `IntentFilter` in you splash screen activity and from splash screen activity you have to link your main activity using `Intent`.

Add following code to your splash screen activity.

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

How ever keeping an entire activity is not the best way to create splash screen. See this for more info: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen)

Answer (score 1):

To Start activity first you need to make it Launcher Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<activity
        android:name=".StartingActivityName">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```