# How to use proper method to add Splash Screen

Tags: android

I need a proper way to implement Splash Screen in android. As i referred some examples but they are deprecated

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
     public void run() {
       Intent i = new Intent(MainSplashScreen.this, FirstScreen.class);
       startActivity(i);
       finish();
     }

}, 5*1000);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen)

Comment: Can you show your import section of the Splash class please?

Comment: Further if you will go to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler, it not depecated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad practice IMHO. You should run your app as fast as possible. Users don't want to wait.

Instead of wait just create an activity and assign a windowBackground to it through style file.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
</style>
```

splash_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/green" />

    <item android:gravity="center">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/brand" android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: How to do that in a proper way

Comment: Look at the example create an empty activity and assign AppTheme.Launcher in the manifest, next edit you splash_background drawable