# Start splash screen activity while having main activity hidden beneath and after all layout and measurements are done, hide splash screen activity

Tags: android

So when I open a splash screen activity, is there a way how to run other main activity beneath that do some changing of orientation and measuring until it finds out some values related to device screen dimensions and subsequently hide splash screen after everything is done ?

Comment: Don't use a splash activity. Use the app's theme instead like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832037)

Comment: @jL4 But I want to change activity screen orientation and then change it  back for some display calculations but I want to hide it from user...

Comment: Post your implementation so far, in other to avoid generic answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious now after a week of research that its not possible. Android is made that way. You cannot hide activity while continue running layout there.