# Is it possible android app startup time be reduced to almost zero? (Like Instagram and WhatsApp new updates)

Tags: android, performance, facebook, react-native

In new version of instagram and whatsApp android applications, we are witnessing that they have added splash screens. And when application opens, the splash screen is immediately visible. The startup time seems to be close to zero.
Can anyone say how? Is a new trick used? Or more traditional optimizations have been applied? 
thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess the data already exists on your device so there is little data to request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen)

Comment: @Ryan Mentley Thank you so much, by Abdullah's answer my problem was almost solved.