# Animated splash Screen in Android with out making splash Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

Is it impossible making animated splash screen without creating splash activity in android ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're not forced to create separated activities for dynamic content or pages.
I suggest you to use fragments in your activity 
whenever your splash animation ended change the fragment and load your main content.

Also you can do it with putting a RelativeLayout as root of your MainActivity
and two children in it one for splash and one for main content whenever splash finished hide it and make main content visible. I don't suggest this because it can get messy and first approach is clean and more standard.

Some links on Fragments:

[Tutorial from android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating)

[Tutorial from codepath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments)

[Android Guide for Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)