# How to use animation images in splash activity of Android

Tags: android

I want to make a splash activity like the one in this GIF[image]

I have one question:

Is all of this one GIF file that is added to the activity, or are all the moves coded in Android?

I have no experience with animation in Android. Please guide me on how to make this page.

My question is not that how to implement a splash activity. I want to know the type of image that is used in this activity and how to make these types. Is it a GIF or a Lottie, and how can I make them? Is this something a graphic designer does, or can I make them too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for load gif, you are using Lootie file:

the first step add line to gradle dependency

```
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0"
```

2 step :

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
     android:id="@+id/animationView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:lottie_url="lootieFileName.json"
     app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
     app:lottie_loop="true"/>
```

final step download and add the file to assets:
like [link lootie](https://lottiefiles.com/26178-splashanim-kabala)

[example](https://medium.com/acmvit/getting-started-with-lottie-animations-android-2c225ad2c467)

or

for zoom picture when intent to main activity can use of zoom splash

[zoom splash github](https://github.com/appus-studio/Zoom-Splash)

dependency  `implementation 'pro.appus:zoom-splash:1.0.0'`

build.gradle

```
     repositories {
         maven {
                 url 'https://dl.bintray.com/roman-voronoy/maven/'
               }
      }
```

end add line in activity after `onCreate()`

```
    Splash.Builder splash = new Splash.Builder(this, getActionBar());
    splash.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use lottie animations in your splash activity

hey checkout this https://lottiefiles.com/blog/working-with-lottie/getting-started-with-lottie-animations-in-android-app