# Image is pixelated and streched when SpalshScreenActivity is created

Tags: android, screen, splash-screen

This is my splash screen activity which then directs to my main activity

```
 public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Below is my splash screen xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_purple" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/blogger"
            />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I tried changing the gravity attributes but nothing changed.Below screenshot is the stretched image

[image]

Comment: You should use Imageview with the property scaleType centerCrop

Comment: I tried using an image view with the centerCrop property

Comment: why you are using a logo on fullscreen

Comment: set width and height

Comment: Width and height did not work aswell. it is supposed to be a splash screen that is invoked while the main activity is preparing to launch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen check out this link for splash screen

Answer (score 0):

Only API 23 or later

Just use

```
<item
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/splash_background"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

instead

```
<item
    android:left="200dp"
    android:right="200dp">

    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splash_background"
        android:gravity="center" />

</item>
```

Or Use ImageView

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:scaleType="center"
android:src="@drawable/Icon" />
```

Comment: I am using API 23 + and I am implementing my splash screen the appropriate way. Also, my bitmap has different sizes xxhpi, hdpi yet still giving me a hard time figuring out a solution.