# Conditional splash screen theme styling

Tags: android, splash-screen

The [recommended method](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#themed) of creating a splash screen while the app loads is to specify a theme in the manifest for the launch activity that uses a [layer-list as a window background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832037/5437165).

How can this method be extended to support multiple user themes (e.g. light, dark, pink, etc.) so that the splash screen background can be the appopriate colour?

I have attempted using styled attributes `?backgroundColour` but the correct style isn't set when the initial themeing occurs. I have also tried overriding `getTheme()` in the launch activity but it receives the call after the splash screen is already displayed.

Is this possible to do in Android?

Comment: Can't you just have a different drawable for the night scenario?

Comment: @HenryTwist Yeah that works for system themes but not for user themes

Comment: What do you mean by user themes?

Comment: @HenryTwist A theme set by the user and saved in the SharedPreferences. Normally, without the splash screen, this theme would be selected before `setContentView`

Comment: Ah I see, I would probably add that to your question. When you say "eg. light and dark" it seems like you're talking about the system qualifiers.

Comment: I've done that now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use initial activity with a background that use a color depends on the dark and light mode.

If you want to make your activity look like a splash screen you can use the following code;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Where this layout uses the icon on the center with a dynamic background color
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    // This is where you set theme colors to the status bars, etc.
    UtilTheme.changeThemeColors(TAB_COLOR_START, null, this);

    // Your logic
}
```

Comment: This doesn't style the splash screen, it's just using another layout that it inflates isn't it? There's a white flicker that these types of solutions have.