# Android MainActivity gets called twice on launch

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

If you simply put a log statement in onCreate, you will see that it android launches onCreate twice

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_title);

    Log.d("myname", "test")

}
```

Usually, this doesn't bother me, but currently I am creating a splash screen that lingers for a few seconds and launches another activity. If it's the first launch - an intro activity is launched, otherwise another activity is launched. The problem arises when I save/load sharedPreferences. Since this double launch thing is happening, the app first launches intro activity, then the other one.
How can I solve this problem? And is it even solvable?

Comment: It will always open the `launch` activity first (as you chose it in `Manifest.xml`), so your way to implement the splash screen is not the recommended one, you can follow this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832037/12053756