# Ionic capacitor: splash screen shows wrong image

Tags: android, ionic-framework, icons, splash-screen, capacitor

I tried to replace the default splash image with the my splash image, but it shows wrong image. The splash screen displays my custom icon image, not my custom splash image.

In iOS, the splash screen shows correct splash image. It doesn't in Android. How can I solve this issue?

I already tried `capacitor-resources -p android`, `cordova-res android --skip-config --copy` and `node resources.js`. All doesn't work...

[image]

This is my `resource.js` in the root.

```
const fs = require('fs');

function copyImages(sourcePath, targetPath, images) {
  for (const icon of images) {
    let source = sourcePath + icon.source;
    let target = targetPath + icon.target;
    fs.copyFile(source, target, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`${source} >> ${target}`);
    });
  }
}

const SOURCE_ANDROID_ICON = 'resources/android/icon/';
const SOURCE_ANDROID_SPLASH = 'resources/android/splash/';

const TARGET_ANDROID_ICON = 'android/app/src/main/res/';
const TARGET_ANDROID_SPLASH = 'android/app/src/main/res/';

const ANDROID_ICONS = [
  { source: 'drawable-ldpi-icon.png', target: 'drawable-hdpi-icon.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-mdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-mdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-mdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-hdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-hdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-hdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-xhdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-xhdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-xhdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png', target: 'mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png' }
];
const ANDROID_SPLASHES = [
  { source: 'drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png', target: 'drawable/splash.png' }, 
  { source: 'drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png', target: 'drawable-land-mdpi/splash.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png', target: 'drawable-land-hdpi/splash.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png', target: 'drawable-land-xhdpi/splash.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png', target: 'drawable-land-xxhdpi/splash.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png', target: 'drawable-land-xxxhdpi/splash.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png', target: 'drawable-port-mdpi/splash.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png', target: 'drawable-port-hdpi/splash.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png', target: 'drawable-port-xhdpi/splash.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png', target: 'drawable-port-xxhdpi/splash.png' },
  { source: 'drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png', target: 'drawable-port-xxxhdpi/splash.png' }
];

copyImages(SOURCE_ANDROID_ICON, TARGET_ANDROID_ICON, ANDROID_ICONS);
copyImages(SOURCE_ANDROID_SPLASH, TARGET_ANDROID_SPLASH, ANDROID_SPLASHES);
```

This is my `capacitor.config.ts`

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.myapp.app',
  appName: 'My App',
  webDir: 'www',
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  cordova: {
    preferences: {
      ScrollEnabled: 'false',
      BackupWebStorage: 'none',
      //SplashMaintainAspectRatio: 'true',
      'android-minSdkVersion': '28',
      'android-targetSdkVersion': '32',
      'android-buildToolsVersion': '32.0.0',
      //SplashShowOnlyFirstTime: 'false',
      //SplashScreen: 'screen',
      //SplashScreenDelay: '2000',
      //AutoHideSplashScreen: 'true',
      GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled: 'false'
    }
  },
  plugins: {
    SplashScreen: {
      launchShowDuration: 3000,
      launchAutoHide: true,
      //backgroundColor: "#ffffffff",
      androidSplashResourceName: "splash",
      //androidScaleType: "CENTER_CROP",
      showSpinner: false,
      //androidSpinnerStyle: "large",
      //iosSpinnerStyle: "small",
      //spinnerColor: "#999999",
      splashFullScreen: true,
      splashImmersive: true,
      //layoutName: "launch_screen",
      //useDialog: true,
    },
  },
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s the new splash behavior starting in Android 12. It shows the app icon instead of the splash screen background.

You can change the icon y adding this to the splash screen theme, but it’s not possible to use a full screen image anymore

```
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/yourIcon.png</item>
```

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen