# Exception while Starting an Activity from TimerTask

Tags: android, android-activity, timertask

I'm trying to start a an activity only after some data is ready in the Service
I'm trying this with a timer task which constantly polls the service for the data readness

```
public class SplashTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Internet is accessible, Running some Spalsh screen Tasks ");
        if(mBoundService.isDataReady()) {
            Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Data is ready in service..");
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(SplashDroid.this, FunWithDataActivity.class), 3);
        } else {
            Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Data not ready in service..");
        }
        Log.i(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Spalsh Tasks fnished..");
    }
}
```

Issue is that when data is ready and FunWithDataActivity about to start, i'm getting the following error

```
07-27 14:53:40.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1042): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `startActivityForResult` from non-UI thread. You can either use `runOnUiThread()` or `Handler.post()`.

Also, you shouldn't really use separate thread for polling. Use `Handler`'s `postDelayed()` function for polling. This way you won't wasted whole thread for simple polling. For an example see: [Repeat a task with a time delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay/6242292#6242292)

Answer (score 3):

`startActivityForResult` has to be called from the UI thread (which is not the thread in which the handler executes). To achieve this, move the `startActivityForResult` code to a `Runnable` and run it using [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) inside the `run()`.

Comment: I believe so. It is just a matter of replacing the `startActivityForResult` call in `run()` with a `runOnUiThread(startRunnable)` call, and in the `run()` of the `startRunnable` object, you can call `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: @Mithun P, You shouldn't really use `TimerTask` for polling in your case, use `Handler.postDelayed()`. This is more robust and resource efficient approach for Activity component.

Comment: @inazaruk You mean '@Mithun P' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) class instead. You can also see this answer for an example: [TimerTask in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014387/timertask-in-android/5014538#5014538)

Answer (score 0):

Worth looking into these post:

[Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

[Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() inside AsyncTask for ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614663/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare-inside-as)

If not resolved,Could u post your code where u r facing the problem!!